# Is this claim about orthogonal projection true?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, projection

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space endowed with an inner product. Let $V_1 \subset V_2 \subset V $ be subvector spaces of $V$.

Let $v \in V$, is it true that $\operatorname{proj\,}(v,{V_1}) = \operatorname{proj\,}(v,{V_2})$?
$\operatorname{proj\,}(v,{V_1}) ,\operatorname{proj\,}(v,{V_2})$ are the projections of $v$ onto $V_1$ and onto $V_2$ respectively, and this projection is w.r.t. the inner product.

Comment: Does the projection of a vector in space ($\mathbb R^3$) onto the xy plane equal the projection on the x-axis?

Comment: No. Consider the usual dot product on $\Bbb{R}^3$, and subspaces spanned by $e_1$ and $\{e_1,e_2\}$ as $V_1$ and $V_2$. If you take $v = e_2$, then the projection onto $V_2$ is $e_2$ (since it's already in $V_2$), but the projection onto $V_1$ is zero.

Comment: Ok, i see. thank you so much !

Comment: I have one more question, please! What if we know that $proj(v, V_2)  \in V_1 $, does this imply that $proj(v, V_2) = proj(v, V_1)  ?$

Comment: With that extra condition, then yes. If the closest $V_2$ vector to $v$ is already in $V_1$, then that must be the closest $V_1$ vector to $v$.

Comment: Got it !  Thank you